# Unetbootin and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, bootloader, unetbootin, syslinux

I use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) on WinXP and I have a Windows 7 iso that I want to make a USB bootable with. Everything works fine. I can boot the USB, but then I come to bootloader screen and I only see one option "Default". As I have read around, it seems I need to change syslinux.cfg, but I don't know how it works.

How should I configure the syslinux.cfg to boot a windows 7 pro installer?

Answer (score 1):

A handy program called [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) can allow you to edit boot menus

Comment: You can tell the user how to use this tool because I think sometime user can't handle this type of software.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with the way you formatted your USB. It should be formated with NTFS and not FAT-32

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative would be

- Run command prompt as Administrator
- type diskpart

  - type "list disk" (without quotes) to list disks
  - if your usb drive is Disk 1 (say) type select disk 1
  - type clean
  - type create partition primary
  - type select partition 1
  - type format fs=ntfs quick
  - type active
  - type assign
  - type exit
- exit command prompt
- mount your iso using [Daemon Tools](http://www.disc-tools.com/download/daemon) (or any other mounting tool)
- copy all the files in the iso to the usb drive